# Angular Setting Default Value for a Combobox

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, I have an input field in the form of a dropdown. The dropdown has 5 options(empty, 1, 2, 3, 4). Options 1,2,3 and 4 comes from the database and in UI, I want to set the input value as 0 when I choose the empty option. Here is my code and a screenshot. What should I do to set that empty field as 0?

[image]

HTML:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="30" class="w-100-p">
                    <mat-label>Dönem Hafta</mat-label>
                    <mat-select formControlName="PlanWeek">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let week of weekList" [value]="week.Id">
                            {{week.Name}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
_productionService.onWeekListChanged.subscribe(
  (response: IBasicModel[]) => {
    this.weekList = response;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <mat-option [value]="null">''</mat-option>
```

For more examples please refer to Angular Material documentation

[Angular Material MatSelect](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples)

Answer (score 1):

you can create one option element and simply bind to 0. The other option is to iterate and bind values from the database.

```
  <mat-option value="0"></mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items"  [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</mat-option>
```

Comment: thanks, but that creates a new element in dropdown. I want to set that value to already existing empty field.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can define a default option in Mat-Select :

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="30" class="w-100-p">
     <mat-label>Dönem Hafta</mat-label>
     <mat-select formControlName="PlanWeek">
         <mat-option [value]="0">default</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let week of weekList" [value]="week.Id">
                {{week.Name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```